# Sending textbox values to UILabels

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

```
import UIKit
var typingSpace = 80

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var typingSpace: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Basically what I'm doing is this: when I type a certain number (let's say 70) in a text box, the label will display something (eg. Your number is 70). I honestly have no idea what I'm doing. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need 4 things

- Add a outlet for your text view so you'll have `@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITExtView!`
- Make `ViewController` implement `UITextViewDelegate`

```
ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate
```

- Make `self` delegate of `textView` on `viewDidLoad`:

```
textView.delegate = self
```

- Implement `textViewDidChange` and put your logic in there

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) { 
    // change your label text
}
```

Here you have be a complete class example

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) { 
        displayLabel.text = "your text"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var typingSpace: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note:* **[@Claudio Redi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245860/claudio-redi)** has supplied the correct answer, this is another way to populate a label from a UITextField.

---

This is one way of accomplishing your task:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var typingSpace: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func handleButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        displayLabel.text = typingSpace.text
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```